# How can I redefine NSNotification.Name as Enum?

Tags: ios, xcode, enums, nsnotificationcenter

I feel writing

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "UserDatabaseUpdated"), object: nil);
```

is very ugly and error-prone. Therefore I want to make it like this:

```
enum NotifyTypes : NSNotification.Name {
    case userDatabaseUpdated = NSNotification.Name (rawValue: "UserDatabaseUpdated");
}

NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NotifyTypes.userDatabaseUpdated, object: nil);
```

But Xcode gave me error:

```
'NotifyTypes' declares raw type 'NSNotification.Name', but does not conform to RawRepresentable and conformance could not be synthesized
```

is this really not achievable? How can I have workaround with this? Thanks.

PS: I know I can make it like this:

```
enum NotifyTypes {
    case userDatabaseUpdated;
}

NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name (rawValue: NotifyTypes.UserDatabaseUpdated.rawValue), object: nil);
```

but this is even more uglier, and I want to get rid of `NSNotification.Name (rawValue:)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily achieve this by using a `struct`.

Define the struct like:

```
struct NotifyTypes
{
    static let userDatabaseUpdated = NSNotification.Name("UserDatabaseUpdated")
}
```

And use it like:

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NotifyTypes.userDatabaseUpdated, object: nil);
```

---

**EDIT:** For using the switch case as you mentioned in your comment, you can use the following way.

Enum declaration with a computed property to return notification name:

```
enum NotifyType : String
{
    case userDatabaseUpdated = "UserDatabaseUpdated"

    // Computed property which returns notification name
    public var name: Notification.Name
    {
        return Notification.Name(self.rawValue)
    }
}
```

Notification posting code:

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NotifyType.userDatabaseUpdated.name, object: nil);
```

Notification catching method and the switch case will look like:

```
func yourFunc(notification : Notification)
{
    switch notification.name
    {
        case NotifyType.userDatabaseUpdated.name: print("Gotcha")
        default: print("Alien")

    }
}
```

Comment: Oooh! Never thought of that! Thanks! But probably the downside of this is that I cannot do switch with the struct members like I can do with enum, right?

Comment: @ChenLiYong: That's the downside of using it, let me try another option

Answer (score 1):

Here is the approach we are currently doing, I guess it looks a bit nicer:

```
extension Notification.Name {
    static let userDatabaseUpdated = Notification.Name("UserDatabaseUpdated")
}

NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .userDatabaseUpdated, object: nil)
```

In addition, you do not have to keep a separate struct/enum/or any other data structures, just extend `Notification.Name` whenever/wherever you need.

Comment: Yes, this is good, and also similar with the accepted answer. Very much thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The best way will be to use Extension then add your struct there like so

```
extension Notification.Name {
    struct NotifyType {
        static let userDatabaseUpdate = Notification.Name(rawValue: "userDatabaseUpdate")
    }
}
```

Now to use it from everywhere you can just call on notification itself like so

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name.NotifyType.userDatabaseUpdate, object: nil)
```

Comment: Wait, you can define new data in extension??

Comment: Yes you can do new functions, structs everything in extension. I don't know who has tried to downgrade my answer which is wired. but no worries just try to add a new extension like I have said and check it your self.

Comment: I mean, usually when I tried to have a new `var` or `let`, Xcode complains that I cannot have new data on extensions. So I learn today that I can have struct! Btw, the accepted answer is a little bit closer to the answer I'm looking for, but thanks for your answer as I learn something new today!

Answer (score 0):

As of Swift 5, a cleaner approach closer to the OP's original goal would be:

```
enum NotifyTypes {
    static let userDatabaseUpdated = NSNotification.Name("userDatabaseUpdated")
}
```

And then posting it would be:

`NotificationCenter.default.post(name: userDatabaseUpdated, object: nil)`

Comment: Interesting. Thanks!

Comment: but it makes no sense to use enum